# Error When Posting to Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth, tweets

I’ve been trying to let a user tweet from my rails app with the omniauth-twitter gem and the twitter-gem and the following code below but every time I go to send the tweet, I’m getting the following error.

```
“Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource:”
```

I have the following code for Twitter set up.

## user.rb

```
def tweet(tweet)
  client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
    config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
    config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
  end

  client.update(tweet)
end
```

## routes.rb

```
resources :tweets, only: [:new, :create]
```

## I didn’t change anything in my sessions controller that was created with devise.

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

# GET /resource/sign_in
def new
 self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
 clean_up_passwords(resource)
 respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end   
end

# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
 self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
 set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
 sign_in(resource_name, resource)
 respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

# DELETE /resource/sign_out
 def destroy
  redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
  signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
  set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

 # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
 # support returning empty response on GET request
 respond_to do |format|
  format.all { head :no_content }
  format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
end
end

protected

def sign_in_params
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
end

def serialize_options(resource)
methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
{ :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
end

def auth_options
  { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new" }
end
end
```

## tweets_controller.rb

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
   current_user.tweet(twitter_params[:message])
   redirect_to root_path
  end

  def twitter_params
   params.require(:tweet).permit(:message)
  end

  end
```

And in my view, I've set up a form for a user to fill out and a button to send the tweet.

```
 <p>
  <%= form_for :tweet, url: tweets_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :message %>
    <%= f.submit "Send Tweet" %>
  <% end %>
 </p>
```

UPDATE: Here is my server log

```
    "Started POST "/tweets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-29 11:26:48 -0500
    Processing by TweetsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",      "authenticity_token"=>"wRGfnEqErGE3enZ2m5/cjBK5N8Ai+z/TprqI5jmsbJY=", "tweet"=>  {"message"=>"Testing Tweet!"}, "commit"=>"Send Tweet"}
    User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY   "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 793ms

Twitter::Error::Forbidden - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource:
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:22:in `on_complete'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/response.rb:63:in `on_complete'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/request/multipart_with_file.rb:15:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/connection.rb:253:in `run_request'
  faraday (0.8.8) lib/faraday/connection.rb:118:in `post'
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:131:in `request'
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:103:in `post'
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/api/utils.rb:123:in `object_from_response'
  twitter (5.1.1) lib/twitter/rest/api/tweets.rb:125:in `update'
  app/models/user.rb:93:in `tweet'
  app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4448031954415073372__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  session_off (0.5.0) lib/session_off.rb:176:in `process_with_session_off'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__810443810394189641__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/70276081720140/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-29 11:26:49 -0500"
```

Comment: Are you sure of your configurations in dev.twitter.com are configured to post and not read only?

Comment: Can you share the server log generated when you hit button to send a tweet.

Comment: @user3490997 yes, they are configured to read and write access

Comment: @KirtiThorat Yes, Ive updated

Comment: How are you setting Environment variables? Are you using `figaro` gem or is it in `.env` file?

Comment: figaro and everything in application.yml

Comment: Can you switch your ENV lines to `ENV.fetch("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY")`, etc? That will throw an error if the configuration values are missing instead of just giving you a `nil`

Comment: @akatakritos i did that but now getting the following error:
"wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the config for:

```
config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
```

If the enviroment variables are unset youll get the 'unauthorized' error.

Just for testing purpose, try to actually input your data instead of the ENV vars... It it works, it means that you have delivered the yml file wrongly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!Not sure why I didn't try this in the first place. Excuse my ignorance but I obviously dont want these codes visible to the public, how do i delivery my yml properly

Comment: Try to find documentation about yml files. Or try to set this ENV vars on your initializer.rb file. The fact is that you are not setting this enviroment vars correctly, so you get the error because they are empty. Just set them correctly (I recommend an yml file that can be ignored by the git and not published) and everything will work fine.

Comment: of course @hamdan. I marked the answer, I'm just confused why my yml file isn't picking them up. thanks though!

Comment: It depends on your server too.. for heroku for example, you could use figaro gem.

Comment: everything is working and i accepted the answer. Before posting another question, wanted to ask how to change this for each user. Right now if another user logins via twitter and goes to make a post, it comes from my account. I tried changing the config.access_token and secret to = self.oauth_token and self.oauth.secret respectively

Comment: If user logs in through twitter, oauth will get its keys for sure.Check for oauth documentation to use this values as you want, but I dont know if is really allowed to post on user's name.